# Eliminate list inside an array if it contains input

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I recently started learning python and working with arrays. I need to check if inside my array an inputted code exists abd if it does delete the whole list that contains it. My code is the following:

```
room = 'F22'
array = [['F22', 'Single', 'Cash']]

def deleteReservation(room, array):
    print(array)
    for x in array:
        for i in x:
            if room in i:
                index = array.index(room)
                mode = validateNum(0, '1 To confirm, 2 to cancel.: ', 3)
                if mode == 1:
                    array = array.pop(index)
                    return array
                elif mode == 2:
                    return 'Canceled.'
        else:
            return "Reservation was not found."
```

But I keep getting the following mistake:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
index = array.index(room)
ValueError: 'F22' is not in list
```

My guess is that the error is inside the nested loop, but I can't find it.

Comment: What output you want?

Comment: I suggest you print your loop variables (*x* and *i*) as you construct them. Then you'll see the problem. Also, the term 'array' is generally reserved for the array type found in the numpy module. What you're dealing with here are lists

Comment: Since the array only contains that element, []

Comment: @LancelotduLac I'm going to try that

Comment: @LancelotduLac I got the list and then F22

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```py
room = 'F22'
array = [['F22', 'Single', 'Cash']]

def deleteReservation(room, array):
    print(array)
    for x in array:
        if room in x:
            index = x.index(room)
            mode = validateNum(0, '1 To confirm, 2 to cancel.: ', 3)
            if mode == 1:
                array = array.pop(index)
                return array
            elif mode == 2:
                return 'Canceled.'
        else:
            return "Reservation was not found."
```

###### Why did You get this error?

Error in this line

```py
array.index(room) # here array is for full list `[['F22', 'Single' 'Cash']]`, and you try to get the index of `F22`from this,

# as you loop through the array

for x in array:
    print(x) # here you get x = `['F22', 'Single' 'Cash']` this is the list from inside the array list, Hence you can use x.index('F22') 'cause `F22` present in x. not in array (array only has one element which is `['F22', 'Single' 'Cash']`.)
```

Comment: Could you tell me what part of my code was wrong?

Comment: @theJohnLewis I will edit my code in a minute.

Comment: There's a comma missing in array

Comment: I understand now, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Yep, I just did. I had to wait some minutes to do it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You should index your main array with the whole array where the `room` from. May be try this

```
room = 'F22'
array = [['F22', 'Single', 'Cash']]

def deleteReservation(room, array):
    print(array)
    for index,x in  enumerate(array):
        for i in x:
            if room == i:
                mode = validateNum(0, '1 To confirm, 2 to cancel.: ', 3)
                if mode == 1:
                    array = array.pop(index)
                    return array
                elif mode == 2:
                    return 'Canceled.'
        else:
            return "Reservation was not found."

deleteReservation(room,array)
```